# Unable to get the response from webservice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a requirement to verify the VAT id from below website
http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/vatRequest.html
I am hitting the webservice of above site with the bwlow code but no use

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#BTNSERVICE").click(function (event) {
                var webserUrl = "http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl";
                var soapRequest =
'<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" \
xmlns:urn="urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:vies:services:checkVat:types">\
    <soapenv:Header/>\
    <soapenv:Body>\
       <urn:checkVat>\
          <urn:countryCode>MS</urn:countryCode>\
          <urn:vatNumber>TESTVATNUMBER</urn:vatNumber>\
       </urn:checkVat>\
    </soapenv:Body>\
 </soapenv:Envelope>';
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: webserUrl,
                    contentType: "text/xml",
                    dataType: "xml",
                    data: soapRequest,
                    success: SuccessOccur,
                    error: ErrorOccur

                });
            });
        });
        function SuccessOccur(data,status, req) {

        alert(status);
            if (status == "success")
            {

                alert('sucess');
                alert(req.responseText);
                }
        }
        function ErrorOccur(data,status, req) {
        alert(status);
            alert(req.responseText + " " + status);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
    <button id="BTNSERVICE" runat="server" text="BTNSERVICE" />
    SAMPLE Application to test service
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

After running above code it is actually supposed to throw "No,Invalid output" but it is throwing error like "undefined error".not sure what went wrong.

Note: THe SOAP request which I sent in above code was provided in below website
http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/vatRequest.html
Could anyone help me where I go wrong?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Run that jsfiddle over http and on button click, you should get: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: fiddle from the delete comment above: http://jsfiddle.net/alfabravoteam/fxj4r3hu/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as I've said in my comment the problem is in the Same Origin Policy. There's no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header present on the requested resource so you cannot make this call from the browser directly unless you disable CORS (but you're not going to do this in production).

What you need to do is build a lightweight service through which you can route your requests. Your service would call the SOAP VAT web service and pass back the results. You could even use the opportunity to do some logic on the server side and further simplify your client JavaScript call.

If you go with a JavaScript / NodeJs solution on the server, I suggest using a SOAP library instead of building the envelope yourself. Check out: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12816/JavaScript-SOAP-Client

Or if you do want to build your own in JS: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-wsajax/

Comment: @Unglückspilz:I have no clue how to do this. Could you please elaborate

Comment: Since you know some JavaScript, have a look at [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/). As you can see on the home page, it takes just a few lines of JavaScript to create a simple web service. Once you've learned the basics, write a service to which you will pass the parameters (VAT number, country code etc) for tax number validation, then call the SOAP web service from your NodeJs service and pass back the response to your client (maybe clean up the response server-side and return a simple JSON). If you think I've helped, please mark my answer as accepted. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks every one for your valuable suggestions.Eventually, I got a solution for this using apigee.com API proxy. I created a API proxy for that VAT service using the apigee.com and using that proxy url  I was successfully eliminated the Access-Control-Allow-Origin error. Now my script is working fine in all browsers.

Comment: Glad to hear you resolved it. Your solution is exactly what I described you need to do, except having to build the service yourself. If you think my post helped solve your problem, I'd appreciate you marking it as an answer. Cheers.

Comment: @Unglückspilz:  I have a question related to this apigee.com.Shall i use this third party API proxy for my web page?will you think that it is a reliable solution?Please reply

Comment: @user3263086 yes, I don't see why not.

Answer (score 0):

Tried the request on SoapUI and worked so I suggest two changes:

- Change request URL to the service URL instead of WSDL. The POST should be querying /taxation_customs/vies/services/checkVatService
- Change the countryCode to ES because MS is not recognized.

[image]